# the remote end hung up unexpectedly9 MiB | 152.00 KiB/s bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

so i am trying to clone one of my repositories from `bitbukcet`. i am using `git bash` on windows 10, but every single time i am getting this error: **the remote end hung up unexpectedly**. i've tried so many thing's but no luck.

**Error**

```
$ git clone https://iamvatsalay@bitbucket.org/iamvatsalay/bookverm-alpha.git
Cloning into 'bookverm-alpha'...
remote: Counting objects: 10797, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9161/9161), done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly9 MiB | 152.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+the+remote+end+hung+up+unexpectedly+fatal%3A+early+EOF+fatal%3A+index-pack+failed